# Bizarre behavior with jQuery DELETE requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ruby-on-rails-4, http-delete

I'm having a really strange issue interacting with a RESTful json interface and can't seem to get anywhere diagnosing it.

Using jQuery, I send a DELETE request to the JSON api and receive a 204 response. Success method is called. Everything is happy.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "DELETE",
  url: "/content_blocks/" + $(this).parent().attr('id'),
  dataType: "json",
  success: deleteItem($(this).parent())
});
```

From Firebug console:

```
> DELETE http://localhost:3000/content_blocks/228 204 No Content 92ms
```

Now I do the exact same thing with another item and get this:

```
> DELETE http://localhost:3000/content_blocks/231 (spinning circle loading forever)
```

The server sends the same response, jQuery fires the success callback. But the response is apparently never received.

If I send a third DELETE request, it works normally again, and apparently alternates this way forever.

I have another ajax call that sends a POST request. I do any number of these in a row with no issue. But if I do a successful DELETE first, then a POST, the POST behaves like the second, unsuccessful DELETE, except that the success method doesn't fire. If I do a second POST, that one works, just like the third DELETE.

To me this seems like something about the first DELETE request, even though it's successful, is broken or not getting properly reset. Somehow a second request resets it.

I'm using rails 4.1.0.rc1 and jQuery 1.11.0 if that makes any difference.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Could this be a jQuery bug?

Comment: Open your Network tab an initiate the AJAX request. Everything will be spelled out in plain English.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. Seems to be the same information, just displayed differently. But it also seems to affect the success rate somehow. When using the network tab, it mostly works with an occasional failure rather than every other one failing. Tried disabling firebug and all other extensions. Made no difference. Firefox's network tab had the same effect as firebug's. Interestingly, it works perfectly in Safari, though not chrome...

Comment: Unfortunately I am not a RoR developer but I would bet that some Ruby code would have helped this question get more attention. Maybe try deleting this question and re-post it again with some Ruby code :)

Comment: And give it a more alluring title such as `Restful service DELETE issues` or something ;)

Comment: Could you potentially be affected by the statements made under **PUT** and **DELETE** **[Here?](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814#highlighter_860154)**